# How to preserve scroll position when calling SetWindowText on Edit control

Tags: winapi

I create an edit control with:

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindow( "EDIT", tabText.c_str(), WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, ...)
```

Then I update its contents by calling `SetWindowText(...)`. But every time the update completes the scroll is set to the beginning. I need to make it preserve its position.
I write to this control a log. That means that the text string is getting bigger.
I tried to get scroll info before calling `SetWindowText()` and set scroll info after the call. This results in a blinking of the control.

How can I preserve scroll position and view the text while it is updated?

Comment: Don't replace the text. Just append the new log text.

Comment: Use EM_REPLACESEL to append text